# calling web api Post method error "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

From MVC controller calling  Web API post method returns the below error:

> "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed"

Below MVC controller Action code calls a helper class method and while debugging I can see control moves from here to next method:

```
public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection form)
{
    Lead_Options lead = new Lead_Options();            
    lead.Situation = form.GetValue("InsuranceFor").AttemptedValue;
    lead.State = form.GetValue("InsuranceState").AttemptedValue;

    Uri url= Url_Helper.GetUri(BaseUrl, service1+"Post"); // returns http://localhost:52985/api/HealthInsurance/Post

    string obj=  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lead);

    Object data = WebApi_Helper.PostData(url,obj);

    return RedirectToAction("Parameters");
}
```

"WebApi_Helper.PostData" is Helper class, a generic method to be sued to call web api:

```
   public static string PostData(Uri url,string obj)
   {
       string data = null;

       try
       {
           using (WebClient proxy = new WebClient())
           {
               proxy.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");
               data = proxy.UploadString(url,"Post", obj); //Here got error
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {               
           throw ex;
       }
       return data;
   }
```

Below is WebAPI Method code but while debugging request do not come here at all

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string  lead)
{
    //leadOptService.AddListOptions(lead);
}
```

Please direct me what wrong I m doing and how it can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP methods are [case sensitive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html). Try with:

```
data = proxy.UploadString(url,"POST", obj);
```

or

```
data = proxy.UploadString(url, obj); // this overloads POSTs the data
```

Also, the `HttpPost` attribute is redundant since Web Api, by convention will only allow `POST` for `public void Post(string  lead)`.

And as a good practice, the `Post` should return a value. At the very very minimum, an `HttpResponseMessage` with status code 201 (for success) or 500 (for errors) and othe rcodes as applicable.